# After Joomla Migration Product Edit Option not working

Tags: php, joomla, migration

My Joomla Site Version is 3.3.3. I have Used Eshop Component for Product Management. I have migrated my site to another hosting and changed domain name. now I am able to add new product & able to edit new product. but I am not able to edit my old products. All old products edit option not working.

So I have enabled debug mode. It shown category not found error. I have fixed that issue by disable friendly URL in Global Configuration Settings. But still my old product data's edit option not working. Please Suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you debugged it at code level?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jitendra..  I does not debug at code level. because same code works fine with old domain and my local. After migration only I have faced this issue. Shall i try this at code level? Please Suggest..

Comment: Please firstly check PHP versions of old, new and local servers.